# javascript getElementById and InnerHTML only running once against html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simple title spacer for my html code so that I don't have to type "&nbsp" a lot and so the code looks more eat. However I have created this:

```
$(function() {
    var subSpace = document.getElementById("subSpace");
    var titleName = document.getElementById("subSpace").value;
    subSpace.innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + titleName;
    return false;
});
```

but it only runs against this code once:

```
<li><a href="#" id="subSpace" value="Start Menu"     ></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="subSpace" value="Tiles"      ></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="subSpace" value="Action Center" ></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="subSpace" value="Settings"       ></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="subSpace" value="Customizations"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="subSpace" value="Windows Search"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="subSpace" value="Microsoft Edge"></a></li>
```

So it runs Start Menu and properly spaces it the way I want but doesn't run tiles, action center, etc. Is there a way to fix this? Am I missing something? I could be way off as I am still learning.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ids are assumed to be unique, so it's only picking up the first 'subSpace' it finds.

Comment: Why you dont use `padding-left` property on the element style instead of  whitespaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a class instead of an ID as IDs are supposed to be unique. Other than that, you could be using CSS to add padding to the left:

```css
.subspace {
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<li><a href="#" class="subspace">Start Menu</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="subspace">Tiles</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="subspace">Action Center</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="subspace">Settings</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="subspace">Customizations</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="subspace">Windows Search</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="subspace">Microsoft Edge</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have multiple elements with an id of `subSpace`. You should use an id only once. If you have multiple elements with the same id, the first element will only be matched.

Also, on a side-note, you should really use `CSS` to style your page (i.e adding spacers/margins/paddings).

Comment: Are you even sure, its defined to match the first one? Think dublicated ids are just illegal.

Comment: It may not be defined that way, but that's normally the way it functions.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicates `id`s. Use `class` if you need to select multiple elements. You can select them using JQuery

```
<a href="#" id="subSpace" value="Start Menu" class="subSpace">
```

In your js:

```
$('.subSpace').html('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
```

I see another answer here which suggests a better way to do this only using CSS. You should consider that too.